# How to select models where all relations have a specific property set to a specific value with Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

Normally, I'm dealing with queries I have a two models and I only need to select one model with a `whereHas` query, which is a greedy condition as it selects as many matches as possible.

Here are my two models:

```
class Part extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'parts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'part_id';

    public function partFlights() {
        return $this->hasMany('PartFlights');
    }
}
```

and

```
class PartFlight extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'part_flights_pivot';
    protected $primaryKey = 'part_flight_id';

    public function part() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Spacecraft');
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's a 1:m relationship between `Part` and `PartFlight`.

What I want is a non-greedy match to select all `Part`'s where all the `PartFlight`'s have the attribute `landed` set to `true`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to find out if all are `true` I suggest you check if none are `false` ;)

```
$parts = Part::whereDoesntHave('partFlights', function($q){
    $q->where('landed', false);
})->get();
```

Comment: Ah, just what I need! Thanks for thinking outside the (boolean?) dude!

Comment: Hahaha. *Thinking outside the boolean*, I like that =)